# Convert float 2-D array to integer 2-D array in Julia

Tags: arrays, floating-point, integer, julia

I know that it is possible to convert a `Float64` into an `Int64`
using the `convert` function.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work when applying `convert` to a 2-D array.

```
julia> convert(Int64, 2.0)
2

julia> A = [1.0 2.0; 3.0 4.0]
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0
 3.0  4.0

julia> convert(Int64, A)
ERROR: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Int64}, ::Array{Float64,2
})
 in convert at base.jl:13
```

How do I convert a 2-D array of floats into a 2-D array of ints?

#### What I tried

I could do it using the following code,
which is a little verbose but it works.
I am hoping there is an easier way to do it though.

```
julia> A = [1.0 2.0; 3.0 4.0]
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0
 3.0  4.0

julia> B = Array(Int64, 2, 2)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 4596199964293150115  4592706631984861405
 4604419156384151675                    0

julia> for i = 1:2
           for j = 1:2
               B[i,j] = convert(Int64,A[i,j])
           end
       end

julia> B
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

#### An answer that doesn't work for me

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.3.10 (2015-06-24 13:54 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org release
|__/                   |  x86_64-linux-gnu

julia> A = [1.2 3.4; 5.6 7.8]
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.2  3.4
 5.6  7.8

julia> round(Int64, A)
ERROR: `round` has no method matching round(::Type{Int64}, ::Array{Float64,2})
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**This answer is for Julia v0.3. For newer versions, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31550270/4689462) of DSM**

Use the `int` function:

```
julia> a = rand(2,2)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
0.145651  0.362497
0.879268  0.753001

julia> int(a)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
0  0
1  1
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is the easiest to type.

Comment: This is deprecated on the soon-to-be-released 0.4 in favor of the methods in @DSM's answer, which explicitly state *how* to convert to `Int`.

Comment: On Julia 0.5: ERROR: UndefVarError: int not defined

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer anymore since it clearly doesn't work

Answer (score 19):

You can convert a 2x2 array of floats into a 2x2 array of ints very easily, after you decide how you want rounding to be handled:

```
julia> A = [1.0 -0.3; 3.9 4.5]
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  -0.3
 3.9   4.5

julia> round.(Int, A)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0
 4  4

julia> floor.(Int, A)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  -1
 3   4

julia> trunc.(Int, A)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0
 3  4

julia> ceil.(Int, A)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0
 4  5
```

Comment: Do you know why I get the output `julia> round([1.2 3.4], Int64)
ERROR: 'round' has no method matching round(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Type{Int64})`

Comment: @ILiketoCode: you're doing it the wrong way around.

Comment: See my edited question where I try it the right way round and it still doesn't work...

Comment: @ILiketoCode: I'm not sure what's going on, then -- I just tried it again with a fresh build, Version 0.4.0-dev+6177 (2015-07-22 19:39 UTC), and it worked just fine, and gave me `2x2 Array{Int64,2}: 1  3  6  8` on your example.

Comment: It's new functionality in 0.4.  On 0.3 you can do `convert(Array{Int}, round(A))`.

Comment: Is there a stable release for 0.4? It seems the latest release is 0.3.10

Comment: That's correct.  This will be the preferred syntax once 0.4 is released (soon).  Until then, I'd recommend using the [Compat.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl) package, which enables the use of these new methods simply by `using Compat`.

Comment: Note that these functions can still throw an `InexactError()`. For example, `round(Int64, convert(Float64, typemax(Int64)))`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use map, which preserves the matrix dimensions, and does not depend on vectorized methods:

```
julia> x = rand(2,2)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.279777  0.610333
 0.277234  0.947914

julia> map(y->round(Int,y), x)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  1
 0  1
```

Comment: I've tested this implementation and the broadbasting methods in DSM's answer using btime, and in runtime they are similar in performance a = rand(10000,10000)
(at)btime map(y->round(Int,y), a)  # 501.133 ms vs (at)btime round.(Int, a)  #489.392 ms